# Error running UT - BeanCreationException No property update found Custom Repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test, spring-repositories

While running below UT `CarRepositoryTest` seeing following error Is I am missing any configuration here?

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'itemRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Failed to create query for method public abstract void
>   com.dms.repository.interfaces.CustomItemRepository.update(java.util.List)!
>   No property update found for type InventoryItemEntity!

Annotated with UT with EnableJpaRepositories (basePackages and repositoryFactoryBeanClass)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.dms.repository",
                                        "com.dms.repository.interface"},
                        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = BaseRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = Car.class)
public class CarRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired private CarRepository repository;
    @Autowired private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Test
    public void getCar_returnsCarDetails() throws Exception {
        final String s = GenerateUUID.generateUUID();
        Car savedCar = testEntityManager.persistFlushFind(new Car(s, "hybrid"));
        Car car = this.repository.findByName(s);
        assertNotNull(car);
        assertThat(car.getName(), is(s));
        assertThat(car.getType(), is("hybrid"));
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories( basePackages = "com.dms.repository",
                        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
                        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
                        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = BaseRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfiguration {
...
}

package com.dms.repository;
@Repository
public class ItemRepositoryImpl implements CustomItemRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Override
    public void update(List<ItemDTO> dtos) {
    ...
    }
}

package com.dms.repository.interfaces;
public interface CustomItemRepository {
    void update(List<ItemDTO> dtos);
}

package com.dms.repository;
public class BaseRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T,
        I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

}

package com.dms.repository;
public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {
    private final EntityManager em;
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Specification<T> searchUsingRSQLParser(String query) {
        return new RSQLParser().parse(query)
                .accept(new CustomRsqlVisitor<>());
    }
}
```

What configuration should be added/modify so that UT should not fail with a custom repository?